# Windows DNS NS record TTL

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

When editing a zone's NS records the TTL fields is always shown empty.

[image: Edit Zone NS record(s)]

Examining the zone DNS file shows that the NS records may already have a value but it is not getting displayed.

[image: Zone file]

I have noticed that when I enter a TTL into the TTL control on the Edit window for the NS record it updates the zone file *sometimes* which makes me think something is broken.

Does anyone have any knowledge of what may be happening here?

**Edit 1**

To clarify; why is the TTL for the NS records not populated in the control shown in the screen shot? It does not populate:

- if the TTL is different to the SOA default minimum TTL.
- if it is explicitly set to a TTL different to the SOA default.
- at all.

Comment: The default TTL for all records in the zone come from the SOA record. If you want to change the TTL of the NS records then change the TTL in the SOA record.

Comment: @anx Yes. It does.

Comment: @joeqwerty so the TTL of NS records cannot be different to the TTL of the SOA?

Comment: @joeqwerty If I have not misunderstood you it doesn't seem correct. I have many instances where after examining the zone file I can see the TTL for the SOA and the NS records are different, in fact I can see that in at least one instance two NS records have different TTLs.

Comment: @Ablue: What I mean is that if you want to change the TTL of the NS record then you should change the TTL of the SOA record as that's where  the NS record TTL comes from. If you want to change the TTL of the NS record independent of the SOA record than I have no clue.

Comment: @anx I am not asking to configure 2 different TTLs, I am trying to understand why the TTL control on the Edit NS record window does not appear to work properly.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Okay, I can modify the default TTL on the SOA but that will only affect the TTL for records which have not been explicitly set or new records. The problem I am trying to solve is why is the TTL for the NS record not shown in the Edit NS record window even when the record has a TTL which is not equal to the default minimum TTL of the SOA. Other record types are not affected in this way. The control is there but appears to be faulty.